# Отредактировать код. Смысл ошибки

Tags: python, python-3.x, отладка

Вот мой код:

```
numbers = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    numbers.append(int(input()))
for i in range(n - 1):
    print(numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1]
```

Задача кода получить число n  потом n чисел, далее сложить попарно и вывести.

Например:

- получены числа 4, 2, 7, 10 и 5;
- далее они преобразуются в:
  2+7
  7+10
  10+5
  Т.е. 9, 17 и 15.

Ошибка:

> E902 ошибка токена: EOF в многострочном операторе

Код не соответствует стандарту PEP8 или имеет синтаксические ошибки.

Comment: Закрывающую круглую скобку забыли `print(numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1]` <- Вместо нее транслятор увидел `EOF` и сообщил об этом

Comment: Тогда почему ругается на первую строку???

Comment: а я не знаю, он может ругаться не на ту строку при синтаксических ошибках

Comment: http://pep8online.com/ - сразу нужную строчку с ошибкой показал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1]
```

вот здесь скобку не закрыли

```
print(numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1])
```

Иcправленный вариант

Запустил все работает